# How do I create a new branch on remote/origin?

Tags: git, azure-devops, command-line-interface

I would like to create a new branch on remote/origin without creating it locally first.
We have build agents in our build and release pipeline, running a powershell script from Azure Devops, and at a certain point it may be necessary to create a new branch at the git repo server. The agents do not have any local git repos and they won't use any branches so cloning a git repo is a waste of resource and introduces other issues.
How can I create directly a git branch on the git server based on a specific git commit without cloning the repo locally and creating the branch locally?

Comment: Thank you for the help - marking the answer. The command works fine if the agent is in already existing git repo. Is it possible to do this without being in a git repo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To push current master to branch_foo

```
git push origin master:branch_foo
```

Comment: The command works fine if the agent has the git repo locally. Is it possible to do this without being in a git repo locally?

Comment: If you have access (ssh or local) to the public repo `git branch branch_foo master`.